# Result of infinite call to sbrk(PAGE_SIZE)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am using linux2.6.38-8-generic with PAGE_SIZE 4 kb.

I am trying the following code:

```c
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

int main(void)
{
    static unsigned *b;

    while (1) {
        b = (unsigned)sbrk(PAGE_SIZE);
        *b = 0;
        printf("[%x]\n", b);
    }
}
```

Results:

1. Sometimes my process gets killed and including some other processes 
   (as out of memory process)
2. Sometimes my whole PC hangs

I think allocating continuous memory from heap (growing upwards) may crash my stack (growing downwards). And by no means it should go into the kernel region. Because of various restriction made in kernel and MMU.

Then why does my OS hang sometimes?

Comment: Per the standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/brk.html), `sbrk()` takes the requested new break increment as it's parameter and returns the new break pointer.  But you're casting the return to `unsigned`, which is not a pointer - it's an `unsigned int`.  If you're running in a 64-bit address space, you just truncated the pointer from 8 bytes to 4 bytes.  Run your process under `strace` to see what's going on under the hood:  `strace -o /output/file/name a.out`, where `a.out` is replaced with your process name.

Comment: Thanks i used strace and got interesting results. i am using a 32 bit machine.i am having 2 gb of ram.  the last debug i got before getting my system hang was [write(1, "[6d0b4000] \n", 12):. which shows i was able to write upto an address [1829453824]-i.e.=1.73 gb..  and my current process stack start address was [0xb7744000]138866688], i think i crashed my stack ...... also i think  somehow i was able to go into the kernel area ....is it possible ???

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out on a VM with 4GB RAM and was able to capture the following in the kernel `dmesg` log

```
[  257.630016] Out of memory: Kill process 1853 (test-sbrk) score 868 or sacrifice child
[  257.630021] Killed process 1853 (test-sbrk) total-vm:3511196kB, anon-rss:3507052kB, file-rss:60kB
```

in this case, our application making the thousands of `sbrk()` calls was selected for termination by the `oom-killer` and the system recovers and continues to run.

---

The occasional system hang is most likely due to :

- some other system process unavailable to allocate memory.

  *OR*
- the `oom-killer` ends up terminating some other process instead
  (as the `oom-killer` heuristically determines which process to terminate.)